# Conditional replacing in a string - Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, replace

I am very new to Python and programming. I have a file with measurment values that looks like this:

85.2147....85.2150..85.2152..85.2166...85.2180.85.2190.

At the end what I want to have is:
85.2147
85.2150
85.2152
85.2166
85.2180
85.2190

What I  managed using

```
k = (j.replace('....', '\r'))
l = (k.replace('...', '\r'))
m = (l.replace('..', '\r'))
```

is this:

85.2147
85.2150
85.2152
85.2166
85.2180.85.2190.

Now, the question is, how can I conditionally replace single dots, A) if no numbers come after it; and B) if the number after the point is the same as the 6th number (or 7th character) before the point.

Comment: Use regex module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '85.2147....85.2150..85.2152..85.2166...85.2180.85.2190.'
>>> result = re.findall('(\d+\.\d+)\.+',string)
>>> result
['85.2147', '85.2150', '85.2152', '85.2166', '85.2180', '85.2190']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [Python regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and book mark a [regular expression test page](https://regex101.com/) to help you solve these problems. Also, it's good to remember that Python can be run in interactive mode to allow you to test things out by hand very quickly.

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "85.2147....85.2150..85.2152..85.2166...85.2180.85.2190."
>>> target = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+)(\.+)')
>>> match = re.findall(target, test)
>>> match
[('85.2147', '....'), ('85.2150', '..'), ('85.2152', '..'), ('85.2166', '...'), ('85.2180', '.'), ('85.2190', '.')]
>>> res
['85.2147', '85.2150', '85.2152', '85.2166', '85.2180', '85.2190']
>>>
```